# How can I use openssl/md5 in C++ to hash a string?

Tags: c, openssl, aes, md5

I need to hash with md5 algorithm a string in my program.
There is the lib openssl but I'm a newbie about it.
How is possible hash a string using that and where I can find a good doc that teach me how to use this lib, also with other function like aes?

I've tried this code:

```
int main()
{
    unsigned char result[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    const unsigned char* str;
    str = (unsigned char*)"hello";
    unsigned int long_size = 100;
    MD5(str,long_size,result);
}
```

But the compiler told me:
undefined reference to `MD5`.

Why is there and undefined reference to `MD5`?

Comment: It is not really clear what you want to do. MD5 is not an encryption function, but a hash function (which is considered broken nowadays).

Comment: Yes I know.
For example:str=hello md5(str)= 5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592

I want to use openssl/md5 to do that.

Comment: Your data isn't 100 bytes long...

Comment: `#include <openssl/md5.h>` and link to `lcrypto`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should take a look at the [documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/md5.html). An option is to use this function:

```
#include <openssl/md5.h>
unsigned char *MD5(const unsigned char *d, 
                   unsigned long n,
                   unsigned char *md);
```

To which they state:

> MD2(), MD4(), and MD5() compute the MD2, MD4, and MD5 message digest of the `n` bytes at `d` and place it in `md` (which must have space for MD2_DIGEST_LENGTH == MD4_DIGEST_LENGTH == MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH == 16 bytes of output). If `md` is NULL, the digest is placed in a static array.

As for AES, if you also want to use OpenSSL, then take a look at [EVP doc](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/evp.html) and [this example](https://github.com/saju/misc/blob/master/misc/openssl_aes.c) of how to use it. Just note that you have to add

```
#define AES_BLOCK_SIZE 16
```

In the top of the file for it to work, though.

Btw. I can really recommend the [Crypto++ library](http://www.cryptopp.com/) since it's great and has all kinds of cryptographic primitives; AES, Elliptic Curves, MAC, public-key crypto and so on.

Comment: You need to add "#include <openssl/md5.h>" at the top so the compiler knows where to get the function `MD5()` from.

Comment: And it's important that you give the correct length of the data to `MD5()` as well. In other words, instead of supplying `100` you give it `5` as `long_size`in your code.

Comment: I did it but doesn't work.
I think that Eclipse has a bug...because every external function or libs, show the same error "undefined reference to".

Comment: Your problem is with Eclipse not the code itself. I'm not an Eclipse user myself but I would think you need to "pair" Eclipse with the OpenSSL library perhaps.

Answer (score 6):

The MD5 function is now deprecated, so if you want to avoid all those nasty warnings in your code...

Here's a simple example of how to use md5 with OpenSSL 3.0 and above with C++:

```cpp
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

string md5(const string& content)
{
  EVP_MD_CTX*   context = EVP_MD_CTX_new();
  const EVP_MD* md = EVP_md5();
  unsigned char md_value[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE];
  unsigned int  md_len;
  string        output;

  EVP_DigestInit_ex2(context, md, NULL);
  EVP_DigestUpdate(context, content.c_str(), content.length());
  EVP_DigestFinal_ex(context, md_value, &md_len);
  EVP_MD_CTX_free(context);

  output.resize(md_len * 2);
  for (unsigned int i = 0 ; i < md_len ; ++i)
    std::sprintf(&output[i * 2], "%02x", md_value[i]);
  return output;
}
```

According to: https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/EVP_DigestInit_ex.html